# Adding Percentage in stacked bar charts of amCharts

Tags: javascript, r, amcharts, amcharts4

I was trying to set the % symbol on the Y axis on the stacked bar chart using the R implementation of amCharts.
Below is my code with sample data

```
df <- data.frame( date = c('2016-12', '2017-12', '2018-12', '2019-12', '2020-12', '2021-12'),X4 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, NA), X5 = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3), X6 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4), X7 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),X8 = c(2, NA, 3, 3, 2, 4), X9 = c(4, 3, 2, 1, NA, 2))

rAmCharts::amBarplot(x = "date", y = colnames(df)[-c(1)],data = df, stack_type = "100",legend = TRUE, show_values = T) %>% rAmCharts::setLegend(position = "bottom", useMarkerColorForLabels= TRUE)
```

I have tried with some Java script, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Can anyone guide me on how to set the percentage either in the y axis or in the text label?